# Is there a way to disable hard pogo on extreme?

Tags: pc, ducktales-remastered

Extreme difficulty is so unfun when it's mandatory that you have to use hard pogo.  Is there a way to disable it even on extreme without it counting as a cheat?

Edit:  Here's a screenshot of the NES manual regarding how to control Scrooge:

[image]

Comment: Maybe hard pogo *is* extreme?

Comment: @Nolonar If so, that's a pretty cheap way to make the game harder.  They could have been more creative by doing things like increasing the number of jumps it takes to defeat an enemy, make gems disappear quicker, only one heart/one life through the whole game, etc.  Having to press down just takes the enjoyment out of the game.  If I am going to do that, I may as well make the game even harder by playing while standing on my head.

Comment: If I remember correctly, pressing down while jumping to defeat an enemy is something you had to do in the original, so maybe extreme was meant for veterans of the original game? Do please note, that I've only tried out the original for a couple of minutes ages ago, so my memory is not the most reliable.

Comment: I don't think so.  I just looked at the original NES manual by Googling "ducktales nes manual" and it doesn't say you had to press down (see image attached to question).  I also don't remember having to do that in the original.

Answer (score 4):

In the NES version of Duck Tales (first game) to do the pogo jump you have to press A to jump, then you can release A, but must press a down+B combination in mid air to activate the pogo. After the first pogo jump you can also release down and just keep holding B to keep pogo jumping. Note that if you want to, you can keep holding all three buttons (A+B+Down) as this won't interfere with the pogo jump, although this is not so comfortable.

In other words to pogo like a baws you press A once to jump, then quickly down+B till the first pogo jump and then by just keeping B pressed you pogo all the way through ;)

There's an error in the game's manual.

In the second NES Duck Tales game (Duck Tales 2) the pogo jump mechanic works the same way the "Easy Pogo" works in DT Remastered.

Comment: This is what I remember too. Triggering the pogo was a skill I managed to pick up and my brother didn't, which made him decide he didn't like the game.